# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime - TensorFlow 2.1

Tags: python, tensorflow, error-handling

I have a desktop computer and a notebook, when I tried to install tensorflow on a notebook just by using *pip install tensorflow* it worked ok, then I tried the same on my desktop computer and when I tried to run the simplest possible code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.keras import Sequential

print("done")
```

I got this quite complex error message:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)       
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, 
in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, 
in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Uvedený modul nebyl nalezen.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "c:\Users\Mechatrnk\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.1.57204\pythonFiles\lib\python\new_ptvsd\wheels\ptvsd\__main__.py", line 45, in <module>
    cli.main()
  File "c:\Users\Mechatrnk\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.1.57204\pythonFiles\lib\python\new_ptvsd\wheels\ptvsd/..\ptvsd\server\cli.py", line 362, in main
    run()
  File "c:\Users\Mechatrnk\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.1.57204\pythonFiles\lib\python\new_ptvsd\wheels\ptvsd/..\ptvsd\server\cli.py", line 204, in run_file
    runpy.run_path(options.target, run_name="__main__")
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "d:\OneDrive\VŠ\DP - Design of Autonomous Vehicle Simulator\Programming\Q-Learning\DeepQLearningSentdex.py", line 1, in <module>
    from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 50, in __getattr__
    module = self._load()
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 44, in _load
    module = _importlib.import_module(self.__name__)
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)       
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 242, 
in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Users\Mechatrnk\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\imp.py", line 342, 
in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Module not found.


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
PS C:\Users\Mechatrnk>
```

How can I fix this error?

If it helps, my GPU is msi GeForce GTX 1060

Answer (score 3):

On Windows 10, I managed to solve this issue by downloading and installing the latest Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable from [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads).

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow the Software Requirements Instructions from Tensorflow https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#software_requirements ? Seems like you're missing a DLL from CUDA or cuDNN.